# Call a constant from another function

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to access the "const history" outside in the historyInfo function so I don't have to call the historyInfo() function inside the selectOption function. The main problem is that there are two addEventListeners calling the showOption function where the historyInfo function is called. I just want the buyItemPanelbtn click to call the historyInfo function.

```js
function showbrookton(brooktonIndex){

    const brookton = Brookton.find(brookton => brookton.id === brooktonIndex)
    textElement.innerText = brookton.text //fill text element
    titleElement.innerText = brookton.title //title element
    while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) { //removes all buttons
        optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
    }
    brookton.options.forEach(option => { //option is options and the funtion is performed on each option
        if(showOption(option) && (option.text)) { //
            const button = document.createElement('button')
            button.innerText = option.text
            button.classList.add('btn')
            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                selectOption(option);
            })
            optionButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
        }
        if(option.backText){ //this goes back to previous page
            const backOption = option.backText;
            backButton.addEventListener('click', () => showbrookton(backOption))
        } //else close window
    })

}
function showOption(option){ 
    return option.requiredState == null || option.requiredState(state)
}
function selectOption(option){
    const nextbrooktonId = option.nextText
        const history = option.historyText;
    if (nextbrooktonId == "buyItem"){
        buyItemPanel();
        function buyItemPanel(){
        const buyItemName = option.text;
        buyItemPanelName.innerText = buyItemName
        buyItemPanelPrice.innerText = "Price: " + option.price
        buyPanelType.innerText = option.type
        historyInfo(history);
        showBuyItemPanel()      
    }

function historyInfo(history) {
  $(HistoryPanel).append("<div>" + history + "</div>");
}

buyItemPanelbtn.addEventListener('click', () => selectOption());


const Brookton = [
  {
    id: "Bakery",
    title: "Bakery",
    text: 'Choose a Location to visit.',
    options: [
      {
        text: 'Bread',
        type: 'Food',
        price: '$4',
        historyText: "You bought bread",
        nextText: "buyItem",
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you show some more code? Specifically where history is defined.

Comment: I cut out a lot of the code from the functions that I don't think was relevant to the question

Comment: Could you please format your code correctly. There's currently a syntax error (extra `}` before `showbrookton(nextbrooktonId)`) and several undefined variables. Also, you're missing the argument passed to `selectOption()`

Comment: updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Declare the history variable outside as
.

```
var history;
```

and then in the selectOption function

```
 history = option.historyText;
```

Code:

```
var history;
function selectOption(option) {
  history = option.historyText;
  historyInfo(history);
  return showBuyItemPanel()
}

showbrookton(nextbrooktonId)
}

function historyInfo(history) {
  $(HistoryPanel).append("<div>" + history + "</div>");
}
```

Comment: I did actually try that. It results in three "[object History]" being appended instead of the actual historyText string.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have solved the problem. I declared Newoption globally and then set it to the parameter option inside the selectOption function. I was then able to make a const 'history' inside the historyInfo function.

```
var Newoption;

function showOption(option){ 
    return option.requiredState == null || option.requiredState(state)
}
function selectOption(option){
    Newoption = option;
    const nextbrooktonId = option.nextText
        // const history = option.historyText;
    if (nextbrooktonId == "buyItem"){
        buyItemPanel();
        function buyItemPanel(){
        const buyItemName = option.text;
        buyItemPanelName.innerText = buyItemName
        buyItemPanelPrice.innerText = "Price: " + option.price
        buyPanelType.innerText = option.type

        showBuyItemPanel()      
    }

function historyInfo(){
   const history = Newoption.historyText;
        $(HistoryPanel).append("<div>" + history + "</div>");
        updateScroll();
}

// click buy button
buyItemButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    closeItemBuyWindow();
    closeLocationsMenu();
    historyInfo();
});
```